# XML files containing a prolog header should start first with "<?xml" characters

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I find the major problem

```
XML files containing a prolog header should start first with "<?xml" characters
```

in Sonarqube.

The XML file where this failure occurs has UTF-8 encoding with Unix (LF) line separator.

The hex view of the content is just starting with "3C" which is the leading < in

```
<?xml.....
```

So, I don't now what the problem is.
A variety of other xml files of the same structure are passing the sonar analysis successfully.

Comment: Are you sure there is no byte-order mark (that should show up in your hex view, though)?

Comment: Thank you very much! The hex was wrong and there was a bom in the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there is a byte-order mark at the beginning of the file?

(That should show up in your hex view, though)